# Sustituir el valor de una fila con el de otra

Tags: r

Tengo una base de la siguiente manera:

```
SBAN   INDICATIVO      CEDULA    NOMBRE  

1535   121563
1263   148633
1257   151863
1339   486946
```

La cédula y nombre la traje con un `left_join` por indicativo sin embargo algunos no cruzaron y me quedaron con NA

```
SBAN   INDICATIVO      CEDULA    NOMBRE  
1535   121563          123546      JUAN
1263   148633            NA         NA
1257   151863           18946      MARIA
1339   486946            NA         NA
```

Tengo otra base con la cual podría cruzar la informacion por `SBAN` para los `NA` y utilizo el siguiente código b`ase$CEDULA[is.na(base$CEDULA)]<- left_join(base,funcionario, by = "SBAN")` Pero me trae la información errónea

Lo otro que estoy pensando es utilizar un `left_join` para traer toda la información de la base funcionarios por `SBAN` y que la variable que tiene NA tome el valor de la variable de la derecha pero al realizar la función me toma es el primer valor de la variable de la derecha

Ejemplo:

```
SBAN   INDICATIVO      CEDULA    NOMBRE     id     nom
1535   121563          123546      JUAN    123546   JUAN   
1263   148633            NA         NA     123546   JUAN
1257   151863           18946      MARIA   18946    MARIA
1339   486946            NA         NA     123546   JUAN
```

Estoy haciendo con la función:

```
base$CEDULA[is.na(base$CEDULA)]<- base$id
base$NOMBRE[is.na(base$NOMBRE)]<- base$nom
```

Answer (score 1):

Existen varias maneras de lograr lo que estas buscando. La segunda manera que mencionas va por buen camino.

Replicando tu ejemplo

```
library(dplyr)

base<-tibble::tribble(
  ~SBAN, ~INDICATIVO,
  1535,   121563,
  1263,   148633,
  1257,   151863,
  1339,   486946
)

df<-tibble::tribble(
  ~INDICATIVO,      ~CEDULA,    ~NOMBRE,  
  121563,          123546,      "JUAN",
  151863,           18946,     "MARIA"
)

funcionarios<-tibble::tribble(
~SBAN,    ~id,    ~nom,  
1263,    123546,   "JUAN",
1339,    123546,   "JUAN"
)

#Combinamos base y df por indicativo
#Creamos base1 para guardar la combinación
base1<-left_join(base,df,"INDICATIVO")

#Combinamos base1 y funcionarios por SBAN
base1<-left_join(base1,funcionarios,"SBAN")
base1
```

Ahora corregimos los últimos pasos, filtrando también el `id` y el `nom`:

```
base1$CEDULA[is.na(base1$CEDULA)]<- base1$id[is.na(base1$CEDULA)]
base1$NOMBRE[is.na(base1$NOMBRE)]<- base1$nom[is.na(base1$NOMBRE)]
base1

   SBAN INDICATIVO CEDULA NOMBRE     id nom  
  <dbl>      <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>   <dbl> <chr>
1  1535     121563 123546 JUAN       NA NA   
2  1263     148633 123546 JUAN   123546 JUAN 
3  1257     151863  18946 MARIA      NA NA   
4  1339     486946 123546 JUAN   123546 JUAN 

#Eliminar id y nom
base1%>%select(-id,-nom)
```

Otra opción que se me ocurre es combinar por filas `df` y `funcionarios` antes de hacer el `left_join` con `base`.